# Unable to install BlackBerry Plug-in for Eclipse (Broken Repo link)

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am trying to configure [Eclipse BlackBerry Plug-in](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse) following their guide using Eclipse`eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-win32-x86_64` on Windows 7 64 bit.
I get an error while downloading the repository.

The link to the repository ( http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java ) from the documentation is broken. What is the correct link to their repository?

`HTTP Server Unknown HTTP Response Code (-1):http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java/content.xml
HTTP Server Unknown HTTP Response Code (-1):http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java/content.xml
General connection error with response code=-1`

Comment: Any BlackBerry developers out there?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Its frustrating. I ended up downloading the full SDK+Eclipse from their website. I now have two versions of eclipse. grrrr..

Comment: And BB is wondering why developer adoption is low compared to other leading vendors, here is a tip, fix your damn documentations!

Comment: I fought with that trouble for days and i ended downloading Blackberry's Eclipse distribution with the JDE. RIM developer support is kind of lame :S

Comment: Try this link http://www.blackberry.com/developers/jar/win/java
The old link `http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java`
is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

That repository link seems to be broken. I came across this link that may help if you want to install the plugin over an existing eclipse installation.

http://cynigram.com/articles/blackberry-eclipse-plug-in-with-eclipse-3.7/